# How to make multiple template class to have the same type

Tags: c++, class-template, template-classes

There are two template class A and B. How to enforce them to be instantiated to the same type **without nesting one with another**? e.g. If I define the two class like the following:

```
template <class T> 
class A {};

template <class T> 
class B {};
```

Then it is possible that the user may do something like this `A<int> a;` and `B<float> b;`

I would like to force A and B to have exactly the same type, but I do **NOT** want them to be nested within each other. So when someone uses these two class, A and B must have the same type. Is there any way to do that? And what is a good practice to design class like these?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want a single instantiation as A<int> + B<int>, but not A<int> + B<int> together with A<float> + B<float> ?

Comment: You need to provide an actual use case.

Comment: @DieterLücking, I just want both A and B to have the same type, they can be A<int> and B<int> or A<float> and B<float, but NOT A<int> and B<float>, i.e. A and B must be instantiated with the same type.

Comment: @newbie: What about multiple matching pairs?

Comment: @CaptainObvlious, an actual use case can be something like this: A is a row of a file, B is the file parser. In B, you may have A<T> getRow(const int rowIndex) and you want both the parser and the row read from the file to have exactly the same type.

Comment: There is no use case in your post, just a desire.

Comment: @DieterLücking, A and B do not have to be instantiated at the same time. How would you implement the matching pairs? Thanks.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious, see my comment above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't have to nest them in one another, but you could nest them within a third type:

```
template<class T>
struct C {

    typedef A<T> A;
    typedef B<T> B;

};
```

Client just access via C:

```
C<T>::A a;
C<T>::B b;
```

Comment: In addition the constructors of A and B could be private and C could be a friend of both, holding actually two members A and B.

Comment: thanks @DieterLücking, but what is the benefit of doing that? It does not make the code look more elegant?

Comment: @newbie It would prevent users of A or B from accessing them directly and violating this constraint.

Answer (score 0):

if you are planning to use variable of one class inside another class, you can do something like this,

```
template <class T> 
class A {
//code 
};

template <class U> 
class B {
//code
A<U> a; 
//remaining code
};
```